# jquery new Date() works locally but not online

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datetime

MVC project, in my razor view, running locally, this works:

```
<script>
        var userLeagueID = '@(ViewBag.userLeagueID)';
        var playerRank = '@(ViewBag.playerRank)';
        var currentTime = new Date('@(ViewBag.TimeTest)')
        //.toUTCString()
        ;
        //var currentTime = new Date();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (typeof currentTime !== 'undefined') {
                alert(currentTime);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

However, it doesn't work when I publish the site, the alert states "Invalid Date".

I am getting the @ViewBag.TimeTest from my server code like this:

```
ViewBag.TimeTest = vm.LastPickTime;
```

(vm.LastPickTime is a c# DateTime field.).  I bet I need a function running on the c# side of things but not sure which one, there are so many to choose from?  I am going to try a bunch of different functions and see if I get it.

Please help save me time!

Comment: Probably wrong format maybe. But your current code with that `new Date()` should never give an invalid date message. Can you choose view source from the context menu in the browser and paste the actual script you see in the page.

Comment: That was supposed ot be commented out.  I was just testing if it was a problem with the Viewbag or the new Date().  Edited...

Comment: Then try, `ViewBag.TimeTest = vm.LastPickTime.ToString("o");`. Most probably wrong format.

Comment: c# doesnt like that .ToString() argument (ToSTring takes zero argumaents)

Comment: Probably, field is nullable. if that is the case, try `ViewBag.TimeTest = vm.LastPickTime.Value.ToString("o");` with a null check preceding it maybe.

Comment: If i put the Viewbag into a string s on the script side, and alert that string s, it looks normal.  It is something with the c# datetime format and when the site is published...

Comment: Usually by default `.ToString()` doesn't take any argument, but you also pass a format or `CultureInfo` most of the time to customize the output.

Comment: It will look normal, but javascript might not [recognize it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). See the `dateString` section in that link.

Comment: Doing the value.tostring("o") fixed something!  Now I just need to work with the variable!  Thanks Mat!  It didnt originally work because i missed the .value portion of it.

Comment: Glad to help, but you are dealing with a nullable field, be careful that it is never null or a null reference exception might be throwing in runtime in those cases. While you are at it, have a look at that link and learn why it worked, so that you can avoid some surprises next time.

Answer (score 3):

Based on Mat J's comments I found the method/function I needed on the c# side.

```
ViewBag.TimeTest = vm.LastPickTime.Value.ToSTring("o");
```

Fixed it for me!  HUGE Thanks Mat and thank you others for the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your dev environment and prod environment have different `CultureInfo` causing `DateTime.ToString()` to generate different results, and it seems to generate an invalid date format on prod. You can test this by inspecting the script.

Instead of instancing a `Date` with a string date, use milliseconds:

```
ViewBag.TimeTest = vm.LastPickTime.UtcNow
    .Subtract(new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,DateTimeKind.Utc))
    .TotalMilliseconds;
```

And remove the single quotes:

```
var currentTime = new Date(@(ViewBag.TimeTest));
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you building up `vm.LastPickTime`?

I created a scenario that works just fine:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var test = new TestClass()
    {
        TimeTest = DateTime.Now
    };

    ViewBag.TimeTest = test.TimeTest;

    return View();
}

public class TestClass
{
    public DateTime TimeTest { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the view...

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Testing Time</h1>
    <button id="testButton">click Me</button>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () { 
            var currentTime = new Date('@(ViewBag.TimeTest)');

            $("#testButton").click(function () {
                if (typeof currentTime !== 'undefined') {
                    alert(currentTime);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```